# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FsxCredentials' because it is null

Tags: powershell, github-actions, cicd

I have a powershell script that uses the command.

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $FsxCredentials -scriptblock { New-FSxSmbShare -name $Using:sharename -path $Using:sharelocalpath -Credential $Using:FsxCredentials -FullAccess: $Using:sharepermission  }.
```

I passed this

to get this FsxCredentials as a param

```
[PSCredential]
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $FsxCredentials
```

In my cicd pipeline I'm trying to pass the information to this command like this after .

```
- name: Get FSX Credentials
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          $fsx_username = "${{ secrets.FSX_USERNAME }}"
          $fsx_password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "${{ secrets.FSX_PASSWORD }}" -AsPlainText -Force
          $fsxCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $fsx_username, $fsx_password
```

then calling the script like this.

```
- name: Run Script
        shell: pwsh
        run: ./create-tenant.ps1 -FsxCredentials $fsxCreds
```

But when I run the cicd, I get the error in the image attached. Saying  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FsxCredentials' because it is null. What am I doing wrong?

I initially passed the value as a string before having to convert to secure-string. But I'm yet to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use for example [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) or [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) to pass the values between the steps.

However, if you were to take the `$fsxCreds` and try to pass it on to the next step, it would be set in the variable/output as a string and look something like below example.
It would fail the parameter validation because you would be inputting a `string` and not the type `[PSCredential]`.

```yaml
UserName                       Password
--------                       --------
MyUserName System.Security.SecureString
```

Easiest way forward should be to keep it in the same step & `pwsh` process:

```yaml
- name: Run Script
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
   $fsx_username = "${{ secrets.FSX_USERNAME }}"
   $fsx_password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "${{ secrets.FSX_PASSWORD }}" -AsPlainText -Force
   $fsxCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $fsx_username, $fsx_password
   ./create-tenant.ps1 -FsxCredentials $fsxCreds
```

Have not tried to simulate my suggestion, but hope it helps!

Comment: Great to hear @marvis_encode ! Please then upvote and accept as answer :)